# How to start working with libvlc

Tags: libvlc

Hello I am very bad with c++ and I'd like to try to make a little custom video player that uses VLC as the back end.

I am using Windows with Visual Studio, and at the moment I have no idea how to get started with using the libvlc api.

Which files do I need to include? where do I get them? Can someone help?

Answer (score 0):

You should use the libvlcpp c++ wrapper when targeting native Windows apps.